# Networking or harddrive issue?

Tags: windows-7, networking, hard-drive, drivers

On my laptop everything was working fine until I started it up and I got a message that says something like FXE check cable and wouldn't let me boot into Windows.  I ended up buying a new hard drive to see if that would work.  Once I installed the hard drive and loaded windows 7 I went into device manager then got these error messages:

```
PCI Simple Communications Controller   XDriver not found
Network Controller  XDriver not found
Ethernet Controller  XDriver not found
PCI Device:  XDriver not found
```

What I don't understand is why one hard drive will let me boot in to Windows, and the other won't. So I'm not sure if I have bad hard drive or if I just need to install some drivers.
Any help would be much appreciated!  Hopefully this made sense.

Answer (score 1):

When you turn your laptop on it will starts ts POST and then try to boot from a device.
This device can be a harddisk, a floppy, a CDROM etc etc.

On of your BIOS setting is a list of these bootable devices and which one is preferred.

E.g. you may have:

1. Try to boot from CDROM, if none are present then
2. try to boot from a USB pen drive. If none are present then
3. Try to boot from an internal harddisk. If none are present then
4. Try to boot from the network.

What happened in your case is that the laptop did not find any bootable devices with a priority higher than the network boot. Thus it tried to find a boot image on the network. This is called **PXE** boot.

In other words: There is nothing wrong with the network part, but something went wrong with a part before that. Most likely with the harddisk.

---

> I ended up buying a new hard drive to see if that would work. Once I installed the hard
>   drive and loaded windows 7 I went into device manager then got these error messages:

```
 PCI Simple Communications Controller XDriver not found
 Network Controller XDriver not found Ethernet Controller XDriver not found
 PCI Device: XDriver not found
```

A **new** hard drive should not boot anything./ It should be empty and you would need to install an OS (e.g. windows) and all the drivers.

Either you did install windows but not yet the drivers (but did not make that clear in the post), or your 'new' harddisk is a second hand harddisk with an old windows installation on it. In that case: Reformat and reinstall. Never use someone else old installation because there is no telling if there is malware installed.

(Edit: I loaded windows is the unclear part. Did uou install windows? OR did you load it from the harddisk).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your old hard drive was faulty.
That said, the boot loader could have just corrupted. To test this, I'll need the make/model of your laptop to give specific instructions, for now, here are some loose instructions. I don't know what key the boot menu is without your laptop model

1. Plug in the old hard drive
2. Press Power
3. Promptly press and hold the boot menu key
4. Select the model of your hard drive and press enter

If you can't find the hard drive model, sounds like it's gone rouge. If you can find it, it's likely just a broken bootloader/a devastating rootkit

To fix the bootloader, you can follow the instructions [here](http://www.tweakhound.com/2012/11/13/how-to-fix-the-windows-bootloader/)

[If that doesn't work, try using the AVG Rescue Disc](http://www.avg.com/gb-en/avg-rescue-cd), I've used it a few times, and it's pretty awesome